# Including npm packages in Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, vue.js

I have a vue app that is structured like so (auto created by `vue init webpack myProject`:

```
index.html
components/
-main.js
-App.vue
```

I want to be able to include npm packages. For example, https://github.com/ACollectionOfAtoms/atomic-bohr-model. Following the instructions, I ran `npm install atomic-bohr-model --save` and included

`<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/atomic-bohr-model/dist/atomicBohrModel.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

in my index.html file. To use the package, according to the github page, I need to run some javascript,

```
var atomicConfig = {
  containerId: "#bohr-model-container",
  numElectrons: 88,
  idNumber: 1
}

var myAtom = new Atom(atomicConfig)
```

that runs with a corresponding element: `<div id="bohr-model-container"></div>`. So I did the following inside one component that renders into App.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="bohr-model-container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></div>
</template>

<script>
var atomicConfig = {
    containerId: '#bohr-model-container',
    numElectrons: 88,
    idNumber: 1,
};

var myAtom = new Atom(atomicConfig);

export default {
    name: 'myComponent'
};
</script>
```

The problem is, when I try to run the app, I get a blank white page. The line, `var myAtom = new Atom(atomicConfig);`, breaks the application. Why does this happen? My guess is that Atom isn't defined in my component's script. Do I import something in the first line?

Why doesn't this work just like the sample application given for the npm package, that runs just using plain html and js files? Forgive my inexperience, I'm new to javascript frameworks. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just import it instead of including it using <script src>

Comment: How do I import it? I'm used to the import line being provided in the github instructions, sorry for asking

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, to import npm modules in a Webpack project, [`npm-install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) the package, and then [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or [`require`](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8) the module in your code. For example:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
// OR
const _ = require('lodash');
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0v61q19rp)

In your case, `atomic-bohr-model` only declares `window.Atom` and does not export any symbols, so you'd need to import it like this:

```
import 'atomic-bohr-model/dist/atomicBohrModel.min.js'; // sets window.Atom
// OR
require('atomic-bohr-model/dist/atomicBohrModel.min.js'); // sets window.Atom
```

And then your component would use `window.Atom` **within the [`mounted`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) lifecycle hook**, at which point the template would be rendered and `#bohr-model-container` would be available:

```html
<template>
  <div id="bohr-model-container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></div>
</template>

<script>
import 'atomic-bohr-model/dist/atomicBohrModel.min.js';

export default {
  mounted() {
    new window.Atom({
      containerId: '#bohr-model-container',
      numElectrons: 88,
      // ...
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j29oqyrj7w)